# How to store multiple data string in a Parse Object with android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am making an application in which a user A shares some information with selected people/users B,C,D and E for example. User A login from his device and asks B,C,D and E's opinion about a certain product. B,C,D and E can provide feedback in positive or negative. So how can I create a list of users that is stored under the same title of the instant and how can I record aNd manage their feedback as well. Should I create a Parse Array of users for this purpose? I hope you understand my question. I tried to be as descriptive as possible. Best :)

What I have tried:

I have created two parse objects. One for the user who creates the instance and other for those with whom the information is shared with. Is that fine or should there be a simpler way to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What have you tried so far?  SO is better for resolving specific questions rather than providing general guidance.

Comment: I have created two parse objects. One for the user who creates the instance and other for those with whom the information is shared with. Is that fine or should there be a simpler way to do it?

Comment: That's a start.  Showing what you've written so far will help others give you more useful feedback.  You should edit your question to show what you've tried already.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll do it :)